# Google Cloud SQL mysql_query Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to add records into the follow tables using sql on Google Cloud SQL.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS phunter_spark;

USE phunter_spark;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Vote;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Product;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product
(
  id varchar(255),
  name varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vote
(
  userId varchar(255),
  prodId varchar(255),
  rating int,
  PRIMARY KEY(prodId, userId),
  FOREIGN KEY (prodId) 
    REFERENCES Product(id)
);
```

When uploading the Product table it works perfectly fine. Example Product CSV data is:

```
57243,We Are Heroes
57242,Tesla Model 3
57239,Captain Strike
57229,Gmail Mic Drop
57223,Sponge Club
```

However it throws an error when trying to upload Votes. Example Vote CSV data is :

```
129455,57119,1
105600,57245,1
105600,57246,1
139608,54933,1
129455,57242,1
7926,57242,1
```

I'm 100% sure ever prodId in the Vote CSV data is contained as an object in the Product SQL database. not quite sure what I'm missing... also relatively new to mysql databases

The error being thrown is as follows:

```
mysql_query Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint 
fails (`phunter_spark`.`Vote`, CONSTRAINT `Vote_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY 
(`prodId`) REFERENCES `Product` (`id`)) (LOAD DATA INFILE 
'gs://dateless-votes-tenk.csv' INTO TABLE `Vote` 
CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your prod ID column in vote table references ID in product table.

```
FOREIGN KEY (prodId) 
    REFERENCES Product(id)
```

This means that any value inserted in prod id column of vote table should be present in id column in Product table.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

57119,57245 etc in your second csv file may not have reference in the id column of Product table.

Comment: Is this the only possible issue? I've sanitized the Vote data to only contain Votes who's prodId exist in the Product table. So this leads me to believe something else is the issue

Comment: There is no other issue that I know of. The error statement clearly states the issue is with CSV file. Look out for presence of spaces in your vote file. '57229' and '57229 ' are different. Hope you have already matched the columns id and prodid using match or vlookup function in excel.